# Mirroring site with an offset

Tags: wget

I followed answers here https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/12311/how-to-download-all-english-books-from-gutenberg which are using `wget`

I want to download using `wget` from a particular starting offset `http://www.gutenberg.org/robot/harvest?offset=100000filetypes[]=txt`. As I've already downloaded previous files, but it starts from the first page.

How can I avoid that?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic...

Comment: @goldilocks I'm note sure. Isn't it `wget` related?

Comment: Okay, I see your confusion.  No, not really, although I guess wget is involved -- it may even be a culprit, but that's not the focus of your question.  This: `?offset=100000filetypes[]=txt` is a not an instruction for get -- it's part of the URL (the query string) and instructs the `www.gutenberg.org` server.  You could just as easily put it in your browser nav bar.  But I think it does contain your problem, which I'll put in an answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is in this part of the URL:

```
?offset=100000filetypes[]=txt
```

That's a query string with two fields in it (`offset` and `filetypes[]`).

Name-value field pairs in a query string should be separated by an ampersand.  Try it this way:

```
?offset=100000&filetypes[]=txt
```

Without the `&` separating the fields, you are telling the server you want an offset of "100000filetypes[]=txt".  The server then rejects that as an invalid argument and gives you a default of 0 instead.

Comment: why does my browser understand it w/o ampersand?

Comment: "Understand" as in delivers with the correct offset?

Comment: yes! it shows the page with correct offset.